# Why Hindus kill animals for Goddess Mahakali In Nepal and India?

Tags: goddess, sacrifice

Why Hindus kill animals for Goddess "Mahakali" in Nepal and India? God never want to kill any animals.

Answer (score 1):

may be there is not any reason behind that 
but its may be one kind of myth's that came from olden era ... and not in nepal and india there is many religion & country that do such kind of thing

there is one kind of thinking to start and good work or any religious Pooja Bali ( to kill animal in front or near god ) are important to remove all negative energy and make there work more clearly with our any Vignha

Comment: You should cite sources.